# How to rename a table in SQL with join

Tags: sql

I want do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (t1 NATURAL JOIN t2) AS H
.
.
.
```

But it makes this error:  `SQL command not properly ended` in this line.

How I can make it if I can?

Comment: You can't do that, however you can make it as an inner query and then do `AS H` on that inner query.

Comment: If the request is "How can I rename the results of a join" see the answer provided by mustaphahawi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You code doesn't make any sense. What do you expect to be named as `H` here? Both tables? That's not possible. What if there are fields with the same name in both tables? `H.someField` could be ambiguous.

You can make an alias (do `AS something`) only for tables and fields - one alias per one table/field. But not to group tables.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 AS Table1
NATURAL JOIN t2 AS H;
```

Answer (score 7):

You mean like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS T1

INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM (select * from t1 NATURAL JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) AS H
```